# solr distance search with proximity

Tags: python, elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I am trying to do some filtering of results using proximity search and I am finding it difficult to construct the correct query for this.

So, in my index I have the following entry:

```
      {
        "aff":"lg electronics",
        "shortuuid":"sddsd3ww",
        "name":"changhee kim",
        "id":"hjgjh-7678ghjhjhj-fdsfdg",
        "_version_":1764697833293742080},
```

I try a small variation of the name:

```
import requests

name="changhee kim a"
org="lg electronics"

requests.get('http://localhost:8983/solr/searcher/select', params={
'q': f'"{name}"~10 AND "{org}"~1',
'wt': 'json',
'rows': 1,
'start': 0,
}).json()
```

and it f'king returns 0 results! why? I would have thought since the query term is two words out including the space it should capture this and show me the result entry above.

*EDIt*

Following @Eric's answer:

```
import requests

name="changhee kim a" # a space and a added at end
org="lg electronics"

requests.get('http://localhost:8983/solr/searcher/select', params={
'q': f'name:{name}~10 AND aff:{org}~1',
'wt': 'json',
'rows': 1,
'start': 0,
}).json()
```

I get no matching results for the above query..

However, when I make edits inbetween the string:

```
import requests

name="changh kim" #deleted two `e` in changhee
org="lg electronics"

requests.get('http://localhost:8983/solr/searcher/select', params={
'q': f'name:{name}~10 AND aff:{org}~1',
'wt': 'json',
'rows': 1,
'start': 0,
}).json()
```

..gives me the correct expected result.

Also, adding chars to the end of the query works fine:

```
import requests

name="changhee kima" #added `a` to `kim`
org="lg electronics"

requests.get('http://localhost:8983/solr/searcher/select', params={
'q': f'name:{name}~10 AND aff:{org}~1',
'wt': 'json',
'rows': 1,
'start': 0,
}).json()
```

so what does not seem to work is when a word is added at the end:

```
name="changhee kim a" #added aditional `a` at the end
org="lg electronics"
```

why so?

Comment: If you're just insert those values directly into your query string, it'll look like `name:changhee kim a~10 AND aff:lg electronics~1` - effectively saying search for `changee` in `name` and/or `kim` in the default search field, and/or `a` with an edit distance of max 10 in the default search field, AND `lg` in the `aff` field, and/or `electronics` in the default search field with an edit distance of 1. The maximum edit distance in a fuzzy search is 2, btw. So then we're down to whether you want a proximity search or an edit distance search, and what your `q.op` is set to.

Comment: Using the `mm` parameter with dismax might also be closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that you would have to escape whitespaces, ie. `name = 'changhee\ kim\ a`, so that solr understands that the edit distance applies to `name` as a whole, which works only if your fields are not tokenized ("string" fieldtype) or use a tokenizer that treats the entire input stream as a single token (Keyword Tokenizer).

Comment: @EricLavault I am a bit surprised by this string field thing. So, (1) when I set the field as string, and try the fuzzy search (with and without escaping the string), I get no results for obvious entries on the index. (2) when I set the field as text and do fuzzy search like you suggested, it works perfectly.. what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [proximity search](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/standard-query-parser.html#proximity-searches) query is a phrase query (double quoted) that allows term
movements to match the specified phrase, ie. it looks for terms that are within the specific distance from one another in the same field.

What you want to do is a [fuzzy search](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/standard-query-parser.html#fuzzy-searches) on two [different fields](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/standard-query-parser.html#querying-specific-fields) (remove the double quotes and specify the relevant fields) :

```py
q = f'name:{name}~10 AND aff:{org}~1'
```

Nb. You will need to escape whitespaces, ie. `name = 'changhee\ kim\ a`, so that solr understands that the edit distance applies to the searched string as a whole, which works only if the involved fields are not tokenized ("string" fieldtype) or use a tokenizer that treats the entire input stream as a single token (Keyword Tokenizer).

Comment: Thank you Eric.. I did not know this sutle difference. I have a follow up question which I have posted on the edit of the question, since I dont understand why adding a word would not give me this fuzzy match. :(

Comment: Essentially everything works as expected except when I append a word to the query..

Comment: also, when I look at the edit distance maximum on the doc you have linked, it implies that the max distance is 2? why so? edit distances can be more than 2 I think? Is there some weird normalisation solr does under the hood?

Comment: It's a lucene limitation; generally the Levenshtein distance is expensive to calculated, especially when you're calculating it against _all the tokens in the index_. As the distance increases, almost every term would be valid against your fuzzy input, effectively making it not useful at all. So it's a trade-off between being useful and being performant, vs allowing any value.

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you for the clarification. it makes total sense.

Comment: @Eric re: escaping.. hmm I am not escaping but iam getting very accurate results from what I can see... I would have thought `python requests` automatically escapes them?

Comment: URL escaping is one thing (used for proper parsing of the request and its parameters, ie. space becomes `%20` or `+`, '\' becomes `%5C`, etc.), escaping characters in a solr query is another thing (cf. query parser). Leaving url components escaping aside, as @MatsLindh pointed out, `name:changhee kim a~10` means search for `changee` in `name` and/or `kim` in the default search field, and/or `a` with an edit distance of max 10 in the default search field ; which is not the same as `name:changhee\ kim\ a~10` meaning search for `changhee kim a` in the name field with an edit distance of max 10.